# Sum of counts from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a dozen of tables with the same structure. All of their names match `question_20%`. Each table has an indexed column named `loaded` which can have values of `0` and `1`.

I want to count all of the records where `loaded = 1`. If I had only one table, I would run `select count(*) from question_2015 where loaded = 1`.

Is there a query I can run that finds the tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, sums over all of these counts, and produces a single output?

Comment: Maybe don't have a dozen tables. Just have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with dynamic SQL.

However, you have a problem with your data structure. Having multiple parallel tables is usually a very bad idea. SQL supports very large tables, so having all the information in one table is a great convenience, from the perspective of querying (as you are now learning) and maintainability.

SQL offers indexes and partitioning schemes for addressing performance issues on large tables.

Sometimes, separate tables are necessary, to meet particular system requirements. If so, then a view should be available to combine all the tables:

```
create view v_tables as
    select t1.*, 'table1' as which from table1 union all
    select t2.*, 'table2' as which from table2 union all
    . . .
```

If you had such a view, then your query would simply be:

```
select which, count(*)
from v_tables
where loaded = 1
group by which;
```

Comment: I actually had that big table, but then it became difficult to manage due to server capacity (4GB of RAM). A repair with sort did not finish after 24h, even with set `myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1g`.

When I created the view and ran the query, MySQL handled it by creating a temporary table, until the tiny temporary space I have filled up.

Comment: @mossaab . . . You probably just needed to partition it by the "question" column.